# external swf shows up as 5 flashing dots

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I'm trying to load a swf file into my main swf. Everything looks fine when I test it with ctrl-enter, but when I open my main swf in a browser it just shows 5 flashing dots where the loaded swf should be. Any ideas whats going on here?

Comment: never mind it had to do with the fact that my text wasn't embeded

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I converted my text to shapes and it worked